# Why doesn't the sinatra-redirect-with-flash gem work with shotgun?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, shotgun

I want to show flash messages using [`sinatra-redirect-with-flash`](https://github.com/vast/sinatra-redirect-with-flash) gem.

Here's my ruby code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require 'sinatra/redirect_with_flash'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'haml'
require 'builder'

# ...

class App < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions
  register Sinatra::Flash
  helpers Sinatra::RedirectWithFlash
  use Rack::MethodOverride

  get '/' do
    @notes = Note.all :order => :id.desc
    @title = 'All TODOs'
    if @notes.empty?
      flash.now[:error] = 'No TODOs found. Add your first below.'
    end
    haml :home
  end

  post '/' do
    n = Note.new
    n.content = params[:content]
    n.created_at = Time.now
    n.updated_at = Time.now
    if n.save
      redirect '/', :notice => 'TODO saved successfully.'
    else
      redirect '/', :error => 'Failed to save TODO.'
    end
  end

  # ...

end
```

And `views/layout.haml` is:

```
!!! 5
%html{:lang => "en"}
  %head
    %meta{:charset => "utf8"}
  %body
    %header
      %hgroup
        %h1
          %a{:href => "/"}= SITE_TITLE
        %h2= SITE_DESCRIPTION
    #main 
      =styled_flash
      =yield
```

After adding a TODO successfully, I expected to see the flash message `'TODO saved successfully.'` on the home page. But no flash messages are shown after redirection when I run my app using `shotgun`. Flash messages are shown well when I run `ruby app.rb` or `rackup`.

How can I solve this problem?

Another problem is also happening when I run the app using `shotgun`. In `get '/'` method, if I use `flash[:error]` instead of `flash.now[:error]`, the flash message doesn't show up on the page.

I am shadowning [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra-the-encore/), but I made some differences:

- `erb` -> `haml`
- Classic Sinatra app -> Subclassing `Sinatra::Base`
- `rack-flash` -> `sinatra-flash`

You can browse whole codes [here](https://github.com/philipjkim/sinatra-quickstart).

Thanks for any answers/comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [shotgun gem](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) reloads Sinatra after every request. The README says:

> Each time a request is received, it forks, loads the application in
>   the child process, processes the request, and exits the child process. The
>   result is clean, application-wide reloading of all source files and templates on
>   each request.

As a result, you will need some sort of mechanism to preserve state between requests that doesn't rely on data stored in each child process.